# Creating a star shape

Tags: flash, actionscript

I'm trying to reproduce the Chilean flag in FLash via Actionscript. I've got the blue box and the red rectangle down, now all I need to figure out is how to make a accurate start shape to finish it off.

Do you have have any pointers in creating a star shape via Actionscript 3?

My code so far:

```
//blue box
var blue:Sprite = new Sprite();
addChild(blue);
blue.graphics.lineStyle();
blue.graphics.beginFill(0x0039A6,1);
blue.graphics.moveTo(0,0);
blue.graphics.lineTo(0,320);
blue.graphics.lineTo(320,320);
blue.graphics.lineTo(320,0);

//red rectanle
var red:Sprite = new Sprite();
addChild(red);
red.graphics.lineStyle(); 
red.graphics.beginFill(0xD52B1E,1);
red.graphics.moveTo(0,320);
red.graphics.lineTo(0,640);
red.graphics.lineTo(960,640);
red.graphics.lineTo(960,320);
```

Chilean flag:
[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not flash, but pseudocode for a star

```
var outerSize = 10;
var innerSize = 5;
var rotation = 3.141592/2;
var delta = 2*3.141592/5.0;
var xpos = 100;
var ypos = 100;

for(var point=0;point<5;point++)
{
   red.graphics.moveto(outerSize * cos(delta*point + rotation) + xpos, 
                       outerSize * sin(delta*point + rotation) + ypos);
   red.graphics.lineto(innerSize * cos(delta*(point + 0.5) + rotation) + xpos, 
                       innerSize * sin(delta*(point + 0.5) + rotation) + ypos); 
   red.graphics.lineto(outerSize * cos(delta*(point + 1.0) + rotation) + xpos, 
                       outerSize * sin(delta*(point + 1.0) + rotation) + ypos);
}
```

If you are going to fill the polygon, you probably need to do something else, but here are the coordinates of the polygon.

If you are plotting lots of stars, I suggest precalculating the coordinates and storing them in an array. cos and sin can be expensive operations.

Comment: Really? You will calculate a constant value of `2*3.141592/5.0` six times?

Comment: if you draw once, it would be unnoticeable, but if this code is used in an enterframe loop it's a bit inefficient

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand this at all. I'm fairly new to programming in AS3. Can I just do a line by line drawing of a star shape using LineTo(x,y)?

Comment: That *is* a line by line drawing of a star shape using lineto. Sorry I can't help any more than that. It is high school level trigonometry. Try running it and see what happens.

Comment: I'll give another crack at it tonight, thank you for you help.